# VBA calling a variable by name inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel, csv

Ok here's the deal: I need to do a comprehensive check in a .csv file (comparing the one in my current sheet to an external one).  I decided to divide the list into 10 equal sections (deciles).  In each decile I choose a random value belonging to that section and use that row number to compare the two sets of data.

Where things fall apart is inside the FOR function. I am looking for a way to go through each decile (starting from rand0) and have VBA check whether the values of the .csv and the Data sheet in this workbook are equal.  If they are not - a function (called get_param) is to be executed.

I dont quite understand how to have VBA go through the FOR function from Dec = 0 to 9 - so in essence from row number rand0 to row number rand9 and perform the inequality check (in the second IF function). The rand & Dec part does not work.  I am looking for clues on how to fix this or on a new implementation to do the same thing.

A few more details: 
n is the number of rows in the .csv file (equal to a couple of thousand).
np is the number of rows in this file (should be equal to n - if not, execute function). ParamLocation is designated automatically - it should be located in a specific location.

```
Sub check_changes_param()

Dim Dec As Integer
Call public_dims
Call deciles    

Set ParamBook = Workbooks.Open(ParamLocation)    

'==========CHECKS IF PARAMETERS.xlsm EXISTS IN THE CORRECT LOCATION==========
If ParamLocation = "" Then
    MsgBox "The Parameters.xlsm file does not exist or is in the incorrect location. Please ensure it is located in " & ParamLocation
    Else
        For Dec = 0 To Dec = 9
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(rand & Dec, 11) <> ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(rand & Dec, 11) Or n <> np Then
                Call get_param
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Dec
End If
End Sub

Public Sub deciles()

rand0 = Int((n / 10) * 1) * Rnd + 1
rand1 = Int((n / 10) * 2 - (n / 10) * 1 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 1
rand2 = Int((n / 10) * 3 - (n / 10) * 2 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 2
rand3 = Int((n / 10) * 4 - (n / 10) * 3 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 3
rand4 = Int((n / 10) * 5 - (n / 10) * 4 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 4
rand5 = Int((n / 10) * 6 - (n / 10) * 5 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 5
rand6 = Int((n / 10) * 7 - (n / 10) * 6 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 6
rand7 = Int((n / 10) * 8 - (n / 10) * 7 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 7
rand8 = Int((n / 10) * 9 - (n / 10) * 8 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 8
rand9 = Int(n - (n / 10) * 9 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 9

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
Sub check_changes_param()

Dim Dec As Integer
Call public_dims
Dim deciles As Variant
deciles = decilesArray()

Set ParamBook = Workbooks.Open(ParamLocation)    

'==========CHECKS IF PARAMETERS.xlsm EXISTS IN THE CORRECT     LOCATION==========
If ParamLocation = "" Then
    MsgBox "The Parameters.xlsm file does not exist or is in the incorrect location. Please ensure it is located in " & ParamLocation
Else
    For Dec = 0 To UBound(deciles)
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(deciles(Dec), 11) <> ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(deciles(Dec), , 11) Or n <> np Then
            Call get_param
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Dec
End If
End Sub

Public Function decilesArray() As Variant
randomize()

rand0 = Int((n / 10) * 1) * Rnd + 1
rand1 = Int((n / 10) * 2 - (n / 10) * 1 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 1
rand2 = Int((n / 10) * 3 - (n / 10) * 2 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 2
rand3 = Int((n / 10) * 4 - (n / 10) * 3 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 3
rand4 = Int((n / 10) * 5 - (n / 10) * 4 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 4
rand5 = Int((n / 10) * 6 - (n / 10) * 5 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 5
rand6 = Int((n / 10) * 7 - (n / 10) * 6 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 6
rand7 = Int((n / 10) * 8 - (n / 10) * 7 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 7
rand8 = Int((n / 10) * 9 - (n / 10) * 8 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 8
rand9 = Int(n - (n / 10) * 9 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 9
decilesArray= Array(rand0,rand1,rand2,rand3,rand4,rand5,rand6,rand7,rand8,rand9)
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked beautifully, thank you! Now I'll spend some time to understand WHY and HOW it works.

Answer (score 0):

I propose this correction,

1. public dim statements should be defined outside sub or functions.
2. use an array instead of concatenation to refer to a variable, `rand` & `dec` is not a correct VBA syntax to address `rand0, ... rand9` variables.

   ```
   Dim rand(9)
   Sub check_changes_param()

   Dim Dec As Integer, n
   ' Call public_dims ' put dim instructions as first instructions of this module
   n = 10 'modify 10 to reflect correct value
   Call deciles(n)

   Set ParamBook = Workbooks.Open(ParamLocation)

   '==========CHECKS IF PARAMETERS.xlsm EXISTS IN THE CORRECT  LOCATION==========
   If ParamLocation = "" Then
   MsgBox "The Parameters.xlsm file does not exist or is in the incorrect location. Please ensure it is located in " & ParamLocation
   Else
       For Dec = 0 To 9
           If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(rand(Dec), 11) <> ParamBook.Sheets("Data").Cells(rand(Dec), 11) Or n <> np Then
               Call get_param
               Exit For
           End If
       Next Dec
   End If
   End Sub   

   Public Sub deciles(n)   
       rand(0) = Int((n / 10) * 1) * Rnd + 1
       For i = 1 To 8
           rand(i) = Int((n / 10) * (i + 1) - (n / 10) * (i + 1) + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) *  i
       Next
       rand(9) = Int(n - (n / 10) * 9 + 1) * Rnd + (n / 10) * 9
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Also a very clever solution. Using an array works - thank you for this. Also thanks for the clever notation of the deciles, I will use this in the future definately.